# SQL Aggregate Function from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

So i have one table with 4 fields = the 1st is date,2nd is first balance, 3rd is mutations, 4th is end balance.

below images has 2 tables, the first tables is the original tables, i have to make queries so it can showed up like the second table.

*the **SALDO AWAL** is getting **yesterday** data of **SALDO PENUTUPAN**

*the **SALDO PENUTUPAN** is getting data from **SALDO AWAL + MUTASI**

AND  so on until the data looks like the second table

[image]

```
UPDATE TRANSAKSI SET SALDO_AWAL = (SELECT t2.SALDO_PENUTUPAN
               FROM TRANSAKSI t2 
               WHERE t2.TANGGAL = '2015-10-10')where TANGGAL > '2015-10-10'
```

ABOVE is my sample code, but i think it was did not work well, so i need u guys help, Thank You

Comment: Is there some id column in the table? is tanggal unique? Also, do you need to update the table or just query the data in the second way?

Comment: There is no ID, just one table with 4 fields, query the data using UPDATE statement

Comment: is tanggal column unique?

Comment: Yes, it's a date, must filled with the day after

Comment: Also, what do you mean by *query the data using UPDATE*? Do you want to *SELECT* or *UPDATE* ?

Comment: update the table so the result be like the second table in that images

Comment: the first table in images  is the original one, how to UPDATE the table so it looks like the second table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `tanggal` is unique, you can use this:

```
with cte(tanggal, saldo_awal, mutasi, saldo_penutupan) as (
    select
        tanggal,
        lag(saldo_penutupan, 1, 0) over (order by tanggal) saldo_awal,
        mutasi,
        saldo_penutupan
    from (
        select
            tanggal,
            mutasi,
            sum(mutasi) over (order by tanggal) saldo_penutupan
        from TRANSAKSI
    ) t
)
update t1
set t1.saldo_awal       = t2.saldo_awal,
    t1.saldo_penutupan  = t2.saldo_penutupan
from TRANSAKSI t1 join cte t2
on t1.tanggal = t2.tanggal
```

Comment: wow !!! great !!!. how can u be so smart ???? THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!!! it worked now !! thx XD